# How to set "Open" preselected with "attachment" Content-disposition

Tags: java, spring, download, content-disposition

I have a PDF file I generate with my application with Spring MVC, and when I click on the file image, the classic popin asks me if I want to open the file or if I want to download it.

Currently, when the popin appears, the save checkbox is preselected, but I would like that the open checkbox is preselected.

I tried this :

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.pdf"
```

instead of

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.pdf"
```

But this opens the PDF file in the browser, and we just want the popin with the open checkbox preselected.

So the question is : is there a way to define it with Spring or do you think it comes from elsewhere ?

(sorry if my english is bad ^^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer, it was from the Firefox Options

Options --> Applications --> Choose "Always ask" for PDF